# How to call a method after text complete in edit text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have tried to search place on map by taking input from edit text, I have two edit text; one is for source location and another is for destination, when user input source destination and move to the next (or we can say on focus lost) than "the place entered by user is point out with marker on the map".

But here when I input GUJRAT UNIVERSITY than it takes GUJRAT and UNIVERSITY as Different different VALUE.

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                           // findPlaceWaypoints();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            findPlaceWaypoints();
                        }
                    });
```

but it search every word  i.e. MADHYA PRADES then it search MADHYA and PRADES and every possible words related to **MADHYA PRADES**. I want to all that text as **ONE VALUE** which is typed in EDIT TEXT.

This is my findPlaceWaypoints method:

```
 private void findPlaceWaypoints() {
        String location = et.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        if (location == null || location.equals("")) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Place is entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
        try {
            // encoding special characters like space in the user input place
            location = URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(location), "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String address = "address=" + location;
        String sensor = "sensor=true";

        // url , from where the geocoding data is fetched
        url = url + address + "&" + sensor;

        // Instantiating DownloadTask to get places from Google Geocoding service
        // in a non-ui thread
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading the geocoding places
        downloadTask.execute(url);
    }
```

Comment: Can You explain your query in detail?

Comment: Does You need it for search?

Comment: If you write it in the same edittext than it takes as it is like GUJARAT UNIVERSITY as it is.

Comment: Please show us the code you have written in `findPlaceWaypoints();` method

Comment: see i have added in the main questioon , thx for the efforts

Answer (score 0):

try this it may helps you:

```
edSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String strname = edSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: its still taking every word as different different value,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with edittext, it has to do with the geocoding api. What it usually sends in response is an array of objects(Places) like the template below.

```
results[]: {
 types[]: string,
 formatted_address: string,
 address_components[]: {
   short_name: string,
   long_name: string,
   postcode_localities[]: string,
   types[]: string
 },
 partial_match: boolean,
 place_id: string,
 postcode_localities[]: string,
 geometry: {
   location: LatLng,
   location_type: GeocoderLocationType
   viewport: LatLngBounds,
   bounds: LatLngBounds
 }
}
```

These objects are all the places that matches the query(i.e. MADHYA PRADES, MADHYA, PRADES).

What you can check for the exact match is the field named "partial_match" in the response object. It is an exact match if partial_match is false, partial match otherwise.

Hope this helps.